# If $w = e^{2i\pi/5} $, then $1 + w + w^{2} + w^{3} + 5w^{4} + 4w^{5} + 4w^{6} + 4w^{7} + 4w^{8} + 5w^{9}$=?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

If  $w = e^{i\frac{2\pi}5} $, then $1 + w + w^{2} + w^{3} + 5w^{4} + 4w^{5} + 4w^{6} + 4w^{7} + 4w^{8} + 5w^{9}$ =?

I substituted $w$ into the expression and combined similar terms. I then tried to see which terns had real or imaginary parts that would cancel. That didn't work out.
There's an annoying trick in this problem.

Comment: Should this be $e^{2\pi /5}$ or $e^{2\pi i/5}$ ?

Comment: I suppose it should have been $e^{2\pi i/5}$ (and that's what I misread the problem statement for). If it shall indeed be $e^{2\pi /5}$, my answer is wrong [the change won't be huge, but the result is much different]. Can you clarify?

Comment: yes, an i was missing. thanks

Comment: $\color{#c00}{w^5=1}\,$ so by the ubiquitous [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242), we first evaluate $\,f(w)\bmod \color{#c00}{w^5-1}\,$ using $\,w^{k+5} = w^k,\,$ which yields $\,5w^4 + \color{#0a0}{5(w^4\!+\!w^3\!+\!w^2\!+\!w\!+\!1)} = 5w^4 = 5/w,\,$ because the $\rm\color{#0a0}{second}$ summand in the sum is obviously equal   to: $\ \ \color{#0a0}{5(\color{#c00}{w^5\!-\!1})/(w\!-\!1)} = 0,\,$ by $w\neq 1.\ \ $

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gre Question Complex Number (plug and chug)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179804/gre-question-complex-number-plug-and-chug)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is that $w^5 = 1$ and $w \neq 1$ implies that

$$1+w+w^2+w^3+w^4 = 0.$$

Use that twice.

Comment: Oy, I read $e^{2\pi i/5}$.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this question comes from a practice math subject GRE, where $w$ is indeed $e^{2\pi i/5}$. See #43 of Form GR0568, the most recent practice test from 2008.

Comment: you're right. i just checked, but there is no explanation of the solution.

Comment: @animalcroc Recall that for geometric sums you have $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k = \frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$$ if $q \neq 1$. Using that with $q = w$ and $n = 5$ gives you $1+w+w^2w^3+w^4 = \frac{1-w^5}{1-w} = 0$. Write $5w^4= w^4 + 4w^4$ and put the first into the first geometric sum, and the second in the next geometric sum $4(w^4+w^5+w^6+w^7+w^8)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer. how is does it follow that equation is 0?

Comment: wow, what a nasty problem. thanks